# Using Google Maps in PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, google-maps

Where can I find the tutorial or example to use Google Maps with PHP, SQL Server and JavaScript?

Example:

If I want to apply Google Maps into my website, which when the user key in the suburb name, then it will return the map of the suburb and show a mark for each of the locations of shops belonging to my company.

Comment: you can find examples to use Google map with PHP on Google

Comment: google maps is just javascript. what do you want to use php and mssql for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the tutorial "[jQuery and Google Maps Tutorial: #1 Basics](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics)" to get familiar. It uses MySQL, but you could probably substitute it with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP class [Easy Google Map](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3801-PHP-Display-world-locations-using-Google-maps.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a good location to start:
[Google Maps Examples](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/index.html)

Just look into the source code of the examples, you're interested in. You can get far with just copy and paste.

**EDIT:** I just noticed, that I refered to the API v2, which is deprecated by now. You might better use the Tutorial for v3.